# How to focus on last cell in a UITableview with scrolling animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a UITableview in my xcode project.In that Comments are listed.How can i focus on a last cell of my TableView with scrolling animation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Below method will find the last index of you table view and will focus to that cell with an animation**

```
-(void)goToBottom
{
    NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [self lastIndexPath];

    [<YOUR TABLE VIEW> scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
}
```

**Code to find the last index of your tableview.**

```
-(NSIndexPath *)lastIndexPath
{
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = MAX(0, [<YOUR TABLE VIEW> numberOfSections] - 1);
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = MAX(0, [<YOUR TABLE VIEW> numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1);
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
}
```

**Add this code somewhere in your view controller**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(goToBottom) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: app  crash at gotoBottom method on**  scrollToRowAtIndexPath**

Comment: @amitgupta , u might be trying to scroll the tableview to an unavailable index,

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that a UITableView inherits from UIScrollView

```
-(void)scrollToBottom:(id)sender
{
    CGSize r = self.tableView.contentSize;
    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, r.height-10, r.width, 10) animated:YES];
}
```

execute it like

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(…);
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(scrollToBottom:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

(You dont need to use `performSelector:…`)

---

Another solution would be selecting the last row. The table view will take care of the rest.

```
-(void)scrollToBottom:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger lasSection = [self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSInteger lastRow = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lasSection]-1;

    //this while loops searches for the last section that has more than 0 rows.
    // maybe you dont need this check
    while (lastRow < 0 && lasSection > 0) {
        --lasSection;
        lastRow = [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lasSection]-1;
    }
    //if there is no section with any row. if your data source is sane,
    // this is not needed.
    if (lasSection < 0 && lastRow < 0)
        return;

    NSIndexPath *lastRowIndexPath =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRow inSection:lasSection];
    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:lastRowIndexPath animated:YES scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom];
}
```

the button is the same.

Comment: fixed some minor bugs. note, that if you are sure your `numberOfRowsInSection` will always return a value of 1 ore higher, you can remove the while and the following if statement.

Comment: This solution need a button click event to go to the last cell . You can use the performSelector with delay for moving to last cell after loading the entire table view

Comment: A button click is not needed. you can call `[self scrollToBottom:nil]` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: /*ROW TO SCROLL TO*/, section: /*SECTION TO SCROLL TO*/)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .bottom, animated: true)
```